# Foreach loop problems in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have the following piece of code:

```
for query = queryFiles
    queryImage = imread(strcat('Queries/', query));
    queryImage = im2single(rgb2gray(queryImage));
    [qf,qd] = vl_covdet(queryImage, opts{:}) ;
    for databaseEntry = databaseFiles
        entryImage = imread(databaseEntry.name);
        entryImage = im2single(rgb2gray(entryImage)); 
        [df,dd] = vl_covdet(entryImage, opts{:}) ;
        [matches, H] = matchFeatures(qf,qf,df,dd) ;
        result = [result; query, databaseEntry, length(matches)];
    end
end
```

It is my understanding that it should work as a Java/C++ for(query:queryFiles), however the query appears to be a copy of the queryFiles. How do I iterate through this vector normally?

---

I managed to sort the problem out. It was mainly to my MATLAB ignorance. I wasn't aware of cell arrays and that's the reason I had this problem. That and the required transposition.

Comment: Do you get an error? What? What are `queryFiles` and `databaseFiles`?

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB, the `for` construct expects a row vector as input:

```
for ii = 1:5
```

will work (loops 5 times with ii = 1, 2, ...)

```
x = 1:5;
for ii = x
```

works the same way

However, when you have something other than a row vector, you would simply get a copy (or a column of data at a time).

To help you better, you need to tell us what the data type of `queryFiles` is. I am guessing it might be a cell array of strings since you are concatenating with a file path (look at `fullfile` function for the "right" way to do this). If so, then a "safe" approach is:

```
for ii = 1:numel(queryFiles)
  query = queryFiles{ii}; % or queryFiles(ii)
```

It is often helpful to know what loop number you are in, and in this case `ii` provides that count for you. This approach is robust even when you don't know ahead of time what the shape of `queryFiles` is.

Answer (score 1):

From your code it appears that `queryFiles` is a numeric vector. Maybe it's a *column* vector? In that case you should convert it into a row:

```
for query = queryFiles.'
```

This is because the [`for`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/for.html) loop in Matlab picks a column at each iteration. If your vector is a single column, it picks the whole vector in just one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can loop over all elements in `queryFiles`, this works for scalars, row vectors, column vectors and even high dimensional matrices:

```
for query = queryFiles(:)'
   % Do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `queryFiles` a cell array?  The safest way to do this is to use an index:

```
for i = 1:numel(queryFiles)
    query = queryFiles{i};
    ...
end
```